# Empty response body in Meetup OAuth 1.0a access token request

Tags: oauth, meetup

A successful **OAuth 1.0a** *access token* request to `https://api.meetup.com/oauth/access/` returns a response with empty body but it should contain the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`. The response status is `200 OK`.

Here are the response headers:

```
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Sun, 26 Apr 2015 19:16:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d1417361f04bd2b49d8441d7277183e461430075769; expires=Mon, 25-Apr-16 19:16:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.meetup.com; HttpOnly
Content-Language: en-US
Set-Cookie: MEETUP_MEMBER="id=0&status=1&timestamp=1430075770&bs=0&tz=US%2FEastern&zip=&country=us&city=&state=&lat=0.0&lon=0.0&s=ddb06082e776a3584371372d7ada246a71c2b652"; Version=1; Domain=.meetup.com; Path=/
Set-Cookie: MEETUP_AFFIL="affil=meetup"; Version=1; Domain=.meetup.com; Max-Age=3888000; Expires=Wed, 10-Jun-2015 19:16:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: MEETUP_LANGUAGE="language=en&country=US"; Version=1; Domain=.meetup.com; Path=/
Set-Cookie: MEETUP_TRACK="id=532f9f2c-71ec-49a9-97e0-e92bac9c47c5&l=0&s=e467a30a7fce8c0b4b6b3fb21e80b934a3ffe6a3"; Version=1; Domain=.meetup.com; Max-Age=630720000; Expires=Sat, 21-Apr-2035 19:16:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: MEETUP_CSRF=7897444a-e0d2-49ff-bcb3-8766976a0e0f; Domain=.meetup.com; Expires=Tue, 26-May-2015 19:16:10 GMT; Path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
CF-RAY: 1dd49ed9eac205e1-WAW
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bug in Meetup's **OAuth 1.0a** flow:
https://github.com/meetup/api/issues/83